# How to make my node OAuth2.0 server(provider) act like an IDP broker through which clients can authenticate/authorize using external Idps?

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, architecture, google-oauth

I'm setting up a new OAuth2.0 server(provider). I want my server to act like an IDP broker through which clients can authenticate/authorize with external IDPS.

Right now the server works fine, with several grant types like `response_type = code + grant_type = authorization_code, response_type = token`, etc..

I want to add a feature that when they access my `/oauth/authorize&CUSTOM_IDP='google'` to redirect them to google oauth2.

What is the flow from now on?

What should I do with the tokens returned from google? Send back to the client / store in my database ? or generate another access token and send them my access token instead of google's token? or should I store both?

Can someone explain the flow? Thank you very much!

[My code is identical to](https://github.com/14gasher/oauth-example)

EDIT: I think the solution is in the picture down below, but how could i implement it with the code that i have provided?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNJ8J.png)